# How jQuery invoices form and delete how buttons add

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am currently working on a dynamic invoice system for myself. But I can't make  it work correctly.

I want to add a delete button to this form but I cannot do so.

I have an invoice table like this in HTML:

```js
$('#addRow').click(function () {
    addItem();
});
$('#items_table').on('keyup', '.update', function () {
    var key = event.keyCode || event.charCode; // if the user hit del or backspace, dont do anything
    if( key == 8 || key == 46 ) return false;
    calculateTotals();
});
$('#taxPercentage').change(function () {
    calculateTotals(); // user changed tax percentage, recalculate everything
});

function calculateTotals(){
    
    // get all of the various input typs from the rows 
    // each will be any array of elements
    var nameElements = $('.row-name');
    var quantityElements = $('.row-quantity');
    var taxElements = $('.row-tax');
    var priceElements = $('.row-price');
    var totalElements = $('.row-total');
    
    // get the bottom table elements
    var taxPercentageElement =$('#taxPercentage');
    var subTotalElement =$('#subTotal');
    var totalTaxElement =$('#totalTax');
    var grandTotalElement =$('#grandTotal');

    var subTotal=0;
    var taxTotal=0;
    var grandTotal=0;
    $(quantityElements).each(function(i,e){
        
        // get all the elements for the current row
        var nameElement = $('.row-name:eq(' + i + ')');
        var quantityElement = $('.row-quantity:eq(' + i + ')');
        var taxElement = $('.row-tax:eq(' + i + ')');
        var priceElement = $('.row-price:eq(' + i + ')');
        var totalElement = $('.row-total:eq(' + i + ')');

        // get the needed values from this row
        var qty = quantityElement.val().trim().replace(/[^0-9$.,]/g, ''); // filter out non digits like letters
            qty = qty == '' ? 0 : qty; // if blank default to 0
            quantityElement.val(qty); // set the value back, in case we had to remove soemthing
        var price = priceElement.val().trim().replace(/[^0-9$.,]/g, '');
            price = price == '' ? 0 : price; // if blank default to 0
            priceElement.val(price); // set the value back, in case we had to remove soemthing
    
        // get/set row tax and total
        // also add to our totals for later
        var rowPrice = (price * 1000) * qty
            subTotal = subTotal + rowPrice;
        var tax = taxPercentageElement.val() * rowPrice;
            taxElement.val((tax / 1000).toFixed(2));
            taxTotal = taxTotal + tax;
        var total =   rowPrice + tax
            totalElement.val((total / 1000).toFixed(2));
            grandTotal = grandTotal + total;
    });
    
    // set the bottom table values
    subTotalElement.val((subTotal / 1000).toFixed(2));   
    totalTaxElement.val((taxTotal / 1000).toFixed(2));  
    grandTotalElement.val((grandTotal / 1000).toFixed(2));   
}
function addItem() {
    var itemRow =
        '<tr>' +
        '<td><input type="text" class="form-control row-name" placeholder="Item name" /></td>' +
        '<td><input type="text" class="form-control update row-quantity" placeholder="Quantity" /></td>' +
        '<td><input type="text" class="form-control update row-tax" placeholder="Tax" /></td>' +
        '<td><input type="text" class="form-control update row-price" placeholder="Price" /></td>' +
        '<td><input type="text" class="form-control row-total" disabled placeholder="0,00" /></td>' +
        '</tr>';
    $("#items_table").append(itemRow);
}
addItem(); //call function on load to add the first item
```

```css
button{
    font-size:18px;
    
}
.myTable {
    background-color:#ffaa56;
}
.myTable {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
.myTable tr:last-child td:last-child {
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright:0px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:0px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:0px;
}
.myTable tr:first-child td:first-child {
    -moz-border-radius-topleft:0px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius:0px;
    border-top-left-radius:0px;
}
.myTable tr:first-child td:last-child {
    -moz-border-radius-topright:0px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius:0px;
    border-top-right-radius:0px;
}
.myTable tr:last-child td:first-child {
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:0px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:0px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:0px;
}
.myTable tr:hover td {
}
#items_table tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color:#ffffff;
}
#items_table tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color:#ffd0a3;
}
.myTable td {
    vertical-align:middle;
    border:1px solid #000000;
    border-width:0px 1px 1px 0px;
    text-align:left;
    padding:7px;
    font-size:10px;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-weight:normal;
    color:#000000;
}
.myTable tr:last-child td {
    border-width:0px 1px 0px 0px;
}
.myTable tr td:last-child {
    border-width:0px 0px 1px 0px;
}
.myTable tr:last-child td:last-child {
    border-width:0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

html page
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="addRow">Add a row</button><br><br>
<table class="myTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Item Name</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Tax</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Total</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="items_table"></tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Item Name</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Tax</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Total</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
<br>
    <br>
<table class="myTable" style="width:70%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Tax Percentage</th>
            <th>Sub Total</th>
            <th>Total Tax</th>
            <th>Grand Total</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="items_table">
        
        
        <tr>
            <td>
                <select name="" id="taxPercentage" class="form-control">
                    <option value=".10">10%</option>
                    <option value=".15">15%</option>
                </select>
            <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="subTotal" disabled placeholder="0,00" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="totalTax" disabled placeholder="0,00" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="grandTotal" disabled placeholder="0,00" /></td>
        </tr>
        
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

I am currently out of ideas on how to do this correctly. So, all I need is once I filled 1 item row, the tax gets in the total table added, and once I change that tax in that row, it changes below as well, and the price has to be changed as well.

Can someone set me on the right track?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to add delete button to this form but I can not do it

The key here is to understand that event handlers usually can be set only on the elements that are present on the page at the moment of setting. Your code failed because you add rows dynamically - they didn't exist when you tried to assign an event handler. However, jQuery provides us with the special form of `on()` [function](http://api.jquery.com/on/) that covers what we need in this case:

```
$('already present parent element selector').on("click", "existing/added later element selector", function () {
    //code
});
```

So, in order to sort out your problem your code should look like this:

```
$('body').on("click", "#delRow", function () {
    delItem($(this));
});
function delItem(elem) {
   elem.parents("tr").remove();
   calculateTotals();
}
```

Note that you have to add `#delRow` button to your template in `addItem()` function and corresponding `<th>` cells in the markup.

Regarding the whole thing, I would also make the tax cell disabled because it wouldn't make sense if users could edit it since the tax sum is defined by percent value below (either 10% or 15%). And the taxes are usually imposed by the govs. and known in advance. I mean you cannot just pay 5.745632% instead of 15% defined by a law.

Also I spotted one minor issue: when I remove symbols in the `price` cell the update doesn't get executed and the related cells' values don't change accordingly. You might want to read about `input` event on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input).

In general it works fine if I understood your ideas correctly:

```js
$('#addRow').on("click", function () {
    addItem();
});
$('body').on("click", "#delRow", function () {
    delItem($(this));
});
$('#items_table').on('input', '.update', function () {
    var key = event.keyCode || event.charCode; // if the user hit del or backspace, dont do anything
    if( key == 8 || key == 46 ) return false;
    calculateTotals();
});
$('#taxPercentage').change(function () {
    calculateTotals(); // user changed tax percentage, recalculate everything
});

function calculateTotals(){
    
    // get all of the various input typs from the rows 
    // each will be any array of elements
    var nameElements = $('.row-name');
    var quantityElements = $('.row-quantity');
    var taxElements = $('.row-tax');
    var priceElements = $('.row-price');
    var totalElements = $('.row-total');
    
    // get the bottom table elements
    var taxPercentageElement =$('#taxPercentage');
    var subTotalElement =$('#subTotal');
    var totalTaxElement =$('#totalTax');
    var grandTotalElement =$('#grandTotal');

    var subTotal=0;
    var taxTotal=0;
    var grandTotal=0;
    $(quantityElements).each(function(i,e){
        
        // get all the elements for the current row
        var nameElement = $('.row-name:eq(' + i + ')');
        var quantityElement = $('.row-quantity:eq(' + i + ')');
        var taxElement = $('.row-tax:eq(' + i + ')');
        var priceElement = $('.row-price:eq(' + i + ')');
        var totalElement = $('.row-total:eq(' + i + ')');

        // get the needed values from this row
        var qty = quantityElement.val().trim().replace(/[^0-9$.,]/g, ''); // filter out non digits like letters
            qty = qty == '' ? 0 : qty; // if blank default to 0
            quantityElement.val(qty); // set the value back, in case we had to remove soemthing
        var price = priceElement.val().trim().replace(/[^0-9$.,]/g, '');
            price = price == '' ? 0 : price; // if blank default to 0
            priceElement.val(price); // set the value back, in case we had to remove soemthing
    
        // get/set row tax and total
        // also add to our totals for later
        var rowPrice = (price * 1000) * qty
            subTotal = subTotal + rowPrice;
        var tax = taxPercentageElement.val() * rowPrice;
            taxElement.val((tax / 1000).toFixed(2));
            taxTotal = taxTotal + tax;
        var total =   rowPrice + tax
            totalElement.val((total / 1000).toFixed(2));
            grandTotal = grandTotal + total;
    });
    
    // set the bottom table values
    subTotalElement.val((subTotal / 1000).toFixed(2));   
    totalTaxElement.val((taxTotal / 1000).toFixed(2));  
    grandTotalElement.val((grandTotal / 1000).toFixed(2));   
}
function delItem(elem) {
   elem.parents("tr").remove();
   calculateTotals();
}
function addItem() {
    var itemRow =
        '<tr>' +
        '<td><button id="delRow">Delete</button></td><td><input type="text" class="form-control row-name" placeholder="Item name" /></td>' +
        '<td><input type="text" class="form-control update row-quantity" placeholder="Quantity" /></td>' +
        '<td><input type="text" disabled class="form-control update row-tax" placeholder="Tax" /></td>' +
        '<td><input type="text" class="form-control update row-price" placeholder="Price" /></td>' +
        '<td><input type="text" class="form-control row-total" disabled placeholder="0,00" /></td>' +
        '</tr>';
    $("#items_table").append(itemRow);
}
addItem(); //call function on load to add the first item
```

```css
button{
    font-size:18px;
    
}
.myTable {
    background-color:#ffaa56;
}
.myTable {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
.myTable tr:last-child td:last-child {
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright:0px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:0px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:0px;
}
.myTable tr:first-child td:first-child {
    -moz-border-radius-topleft:0px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius:0px;
    border-top-left-radius:0px;
}
.myTable tr:first-child td:last-child {
    -moz-border-radius-topright:0px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius:0px;
    border-top-right-radius:0px;
}
.myTable tr:last-child td:first-child {
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:0px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:0px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:0px;
}
.myTable tr:hover td {
}
#items_table tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color:#ffffff;
}
#items_table tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color:#ffd0a3;
}
.myTable td {
    vertical-align:middle;
    border:1px solid #000000;
    border-width:0px 1px 1px 0px;
    text-align:left;
    padding:7px;
    font-size:10px;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-weight:normal;
    color:#000000;
}
.myTable tr:last-child td {
    border-width:0px 1px 0px 0px;
}
.myTable tr td:last-child {
    border-width:0px 0px 1px 0px;
}
.myTable tr:last-child td:last-child {
    border-width:0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="addRow">Add a row</button><br><br>
<table class="myTable">
    <thead>
        <tr><th>Delete</th>
            <th>Item Name</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Tax</th>
            <th>Price per unit</th>
            <th>Total</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="items_table"></tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr><th>Delete</th>
            <th>Item Name</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Tax</th>
            <th>Price per unit</th>
            <th>Total</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
<br>
    <br>
<table class="myTable" style="width:70%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Tax Percentage</th>
            <th>Sub Total</th>
            <th>Total Tax</th>
            <th>Grand Total</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="items_table">
        
        
        <tr>
            <td>
                <select name="" id="taxPercentage" class="form-control">
                    <option value=".10">10%</option>
                    <option value=".15">15%</option>
                </select>
            <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="subTotal" disabled placeholder="0,00" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="totalTax" disabled placeholder="0,00" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="grandTotal" disabled placeholder="0,00" /></td>
        </tr>
        
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

As for your additional question - you can choose a locale to treat numbers as money in your country's format. It can be done by [toLocaleString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString):

```js
var num1 = 145636,
    num2 = 145636;

console.log(num1.toLocaleString('en-US', {style: 'currency', currency: 'USD'})); // US format - 145,636
console.log(num2.toLocaleString('en-IN', {style: 'currency', currency: 'INR'})); // Indian format - 1,45,636
```

Comment: How can I separate the numbers that I write to price into a comma?

sample:
1,500

Answer (score 0):

How can I separate the numbers that I write to price into a comma?

**sample:**

1,500

1,456,36

Comment: where you are formatting and then inserting data into dom. Lines with .toFixed(2). Instead use toLocaleString with chosen settings.

Comment: price, total subtotal taxtotal I want to add? could you add an example